# PHP encoding when inserting data from windows-1256 to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, encoding, insert

I have created an integration between two system and when reading the data from the first DB (with collation windows-1256) and inserting it into second DB (with collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) it has inserted as wrong encoding

```
Insert into TESTDTA.F060116Z ( SZEDUS,SZEDBT,SZEDTN,SZEDLN,SZEDCT,SZEDDT,SZEDDL,SZEDSP,SZTNAC,SZAN8,SZALPH,SZAT1,SZHMCO,SZHMCU,SZANPA,SZSAL,SZDSI,SZSEX,SZDOB,SZCCPR,SZMSTI,SZPAST,SZPSDT,SZMCU,SZHM02,SZPFRQ,SZSALY,SZFLSA,SZUN,SZTRS,SZEFTO,SZTORG,SZUSER,SZPID,SZJOBN,SZUPMJ,SZTDAY,SZLF,SZSMKR,SZTIPE,SZMSA ) values ( 'MenaHRMS','50','Update Employee','1','H2','116088','0','Y','04','113084',N'اباء فارس الهندي','E','00003',' 31145000','1406086','1','115152','M','910001','SA','M','0','115152',' 31145000','N','M','S','Y','NS','010','116088','MenaHRMS','MenaHRMS','MenaHRMS','MenaHRMS','116088','044939','1','E','N','M' )
```

and the result = `ÇÈÇÁ ÝÇÑÓ ÇáåäÏí`

`اباء فارس الهندي = ÇÈÇÁ ÝÇÑÓ ÇáåäÏí`

I tried iconv and headers but it doesn't work.

Comment: Exactly how do you connect to the MySQL servers? And how do you query and insert the data? (If possible please post the code - i.e. a reasonable small yet relevant portion of it ;-) )

Comment: "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" that sounds like MS sqlserver -> added tags `sql-server` and `tsql`.

Comment: Obviously, you cannot fit Arabic characters in Latin-1. Unless you want to base64-encode/decode everything every time or similar nonsense, you'll have to create a table with an appropriate encoding (how about UTF-8?)

Comment: thank you for replays, it is MSSQL servers, i enabled the mssql from PHP.ini and i use class for connection the following is the connection code

$AXDB_manager=new DBManager();
 $AXDB_manager->connect($ERPVariables['DB_SERVER'],$ERPVariables['DB_Name'],$ERPVariables['DB_UserName'],$ERPVariables['DB_Password']);
 $AXconn_DB=$AXDB_manager->database;


and the following is the query generation and execution

$insert_query= new MyQuery('TESTDTA.'.$tableName,"INSERT");
  $insert_query->data=$data;
  $insert_query=$AXDB_manager->query_gen($insert_query);
  $AXDB_manager->query($insert_query);

Comment: I'm using mssql_connect in my connections

please note the first system interface encoding is windows-1256

Comment: it is solved by using below code in the insert statement for arabic columns , 
"N'".iconv('windows-1256','utf-8',substr($VoucherLine['RecordNotes'],0,30))."'";